# How to debug a new Thread in VS2015?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have this code in a WebForm project in VS Community 2015:

```
    var th = new Thread(() => {
        var wb = new WebBrowser();
        wb.DocumentCompleted += wb_DocumentCompleted;
        wb.AllowNavigation = true;
        wb.Navigate("https://www.ovo.com.au/login");
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
```

This is the DocumentCompleted handler, which runs ok, but I cannot debug it

```
private async void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(wb.Url);
}
```

I get this in the Watch window when I put a breakpoint:

> error CS0103: The name 'wb' does not exist in the current context

[image]

**Edit / Solution**

The solution was to enable "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" (in Tools > Options > Debugging > General)

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you're running in release mode.

Comment: lol no, but I've found the solution! I'll update it

Comment: @Aximili, Would you please post the solution as an answer? So you could mark it and it could help other community members who meet the same issue to find and research the answer here.